# how to save multiple checkbox in usermeta and get it?

Tags: user-meta, profiles

I want to create a new part as multiple checkbox in user profile page that user can check their services.

***But the issue is i do not know how to display the checked options after saving as checked and how to display checked options in another page by `get_user_meta`!!!***

my codes:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="service_name[]" value="Architecture" >Architecture<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="service_name[]" value="Builders and Developeres">Builders and Developeres<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="service_name[]" value="Material Supplier">Material Supplier<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="service_name[]" value="Contractor">Contractor<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="service_name[]" value="Interior Decorator">Interior Decorator<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="service_name[]" value="Property Finance">Property Finance<br>
```

the way i save them in user meta table:

```
if( isset($_POST['service_name']) ){
    //$data=serialize($_POST['service_name']);
    $data = $_POST['service_name'];
    update_user_meta($userid, 'service_name', $data);
}
```

*i need your help*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First get the data

```
$data = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'service_name', true);
```

You find an array of all entries in $data. You can do it this way:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="service_name[]" value="Architecture" <?php echo in_array('Architecture', $data) ? 'checked' : ''); ?>>Architecture<br>
```

Untested, but should work.

Comment: thanks my friend. how can i display the checked items in another page? it is for user's profile and i want display them to other users

Comment: On the same way, u just need the user id of the user where the fields stored